# Add data to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write/append this kind of data to a csv file

```
{'ACW': 1431, 'ACA': 6.066, 'ACV': 237.2, 'PEAK_POW': 1.853, 'DCV_1': 192.2, 'DCA_1': 7.72, 'DCW': 1461, 'AC_EFFI': 97.91, 'LINEA_DISTR': 1033}
```

I take it each 5 seconds from a solar inverter and record on this object in my code

```
inverter = {}
```

I have tried with this example:

```
import json
import csv
headers = ['ACW', 'ACA', 'ACV', 'PEAK_POW',
     'DCV_1', 'DCA_1', 'DCW', 'AC_EFFI', 'LINEA_DISTR']
file_csv = "huawei.csv"
inverter = {}

 while inverter['DCV_1'] < 0:
    //......
    //code that take the data from my Solar Inverter
    //......
    with open(file_csv, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        datos = json.dump(inverter, f)
        writer.writerow(datos)
```

I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I have googling this error without success. I don´t know how to figured out this problem.

Any clue or help is welcome

Comment: some one really clever gave me a -1, I dont why? It doesn't help me

Comment: `datos = json.dump(inversor, f)`  Probably because you could have understood what the error says or googled it. The `dict` object should be the first param and the filehandler the second for `json.dumps()`

Comment: OK, thanks @BijayRegmi, I understand it now. I will edit my question to add some research

Comment: Hi, I updated my code for some errors

Comment: What's your question? Please read [ask]. This code is not syntactically valid since Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`. But even if you fix that as well as the indenting on `while`, it doesn't produce that error, it raises `KeyError: 'DCV_1'`. So for debugging help, you need to make a [mre]. You might also want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Comment: Well apart from wjandreas valid suggestions (which are very cruicial skills to learn, if you want people at stackoverflow to be able to help you), it is clear that you are using `dict_object.keys()` somewhere and passing a `NoneType` object into it. It is not in the part that you have posted. If you look closely into actual error message, it will say what file and what line. It is hard to help you solve this without having proper information yet.

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but as my grandfather says, you're right but you're going to jail.
I was just looking for help. I wasn't looking for someone to give me the perfect solution. Just a tip
I'm going to close this question with the solution I've received from other forums.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import csv
#example of data taken from Solar Inverter
#inversor = {'ACW': 65, 'ACA': 0.379, 'ACV': 237.2, 'PEAK_POW': 2.264, 
#'DCV_1': 176.0, 'DCA_1': 0.41, 'DCW': 72, 'AC_EFFI': 90.32,        
#'LINEA_DISTR': -402}

headers = ['ACW', 'ACA', 'ACV', 'PEAK_POW',
       'DCV_1', 'DCA_1', 'DCW', 'AC_EFFI', 'LINEA_DISTR']


file_csv = "huawei.csv"

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    ##......
    ##code that take the data from a Solar Inverter
    ##......
    with open(file_csv, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writerow(inversor)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.